# How do you revert mac terminal in Catalina to factory settings?

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I'm using 10.15.6 (19G2021).

I changed over to zshell but not sure if that's a mistake. Was trying to install git and modify my command prompt and now I have both .bash .z.... files. Ugh. I just want to start fresh. Any advice?

Comment: Surely you revert to your preferred shell the way you set yourself to the zshell ?  That is, you open up Terminal Preferences and set the windows to open with the shell you specify.

Comment: If you want to continue to use zsh then just delete the .bash files. The same goes for the other way around. To set the default shell see this Q/A https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88278/change-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh/88296